# Classical Probability Approach

Tags: probability, self-study, frequentist

The definition of classical probability is

> **Classical Probability:**  If a random experiment can result in $n$ mutually exclusive and equally likely outcomes and if $n_A$ of these outcomes have an attribute $A$, then the probability of $A$ is the fraction $n_A/n.$

In the book [Mood, A. M., Graybill, F. A., & Boes, D. C. (1974). Introduction to the Theory of Statistics 1974. McGraw-Hill Kogakusha](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070854653), it is written that

> difficulty with the classical approach is encounterd when we try to answer the question: *What is the probability that a child born in Chicago will be a boy?*

Why can't classical definition answer it? Isn't it simply $0.5$, as the child's being a male or female is equally likely?

Comment: The first quotation isn't a definition at all: it's a formula for a *model.*  Should you choose to apply it, your first duty is to demonstrate that it is at least approximately correct--and that puts you right back to the beginning: what is "probability" in the first place and how do you measure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should not confuse the philosophical issue of *defining the meaning of probability*, with the statistical issue of estimating the probability of a particular event.  Merely defining the meaning of probability does not allow you to deduce the probability of a particular event.  The only way to assess the probability that a child born in Chicago is a boy is to look at [data on sex-ratios at birth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_sex_ratio).  As you can see from this data, it is standard for there to be more males at birth than females, and hence it is unlikely to be true that the a birth of either sex is equally likely in Chicago.  Hopefully this kind of case alerts us to the danger of making *a priori* statements about probabilities of events, without looking for empirical data.

In relation to the classical formulation of probability, you will notice that it is a count-based method that relies on a pre-existing pre-probabilistic conceptual notion of what is "equally likely".  This is a major drawback of the classical formulation, since it defines probability in terms of a preliminary concept that is arguably a probabilistic determination.  In the quote you supply, the difficulty with assessing the probability of this event is that there is not a clear class of "equally likely outcomes" that can be used as a basis for the count.  The data we have show that male and female births are **not** equally likely.  (And in any case, if we are going to try to determine the probability of a male birth, we should not beg the question by assuming the answer *a priori*.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the classical definition is an idealization.  In the real world things are very rarely so tidy.  Child birth rates are actually a great example.  At first glance, people tend to think they are 50-50, but they are not!  More males are conceived (one theory is that sperm with the smaller Y chromosomes are slightly faster).  More males are miscarried, but not enough to completely undo the 'advantage.'